# How many ways a servlet can be destroyed?

Tags: java, servlets

Can the servlet be destroyed only using the destroy() method called by the contains or is there any other way

Answer (score 2):

The servlet is not *destroyed* when you call `destroy` method. This method is meant to clear any resources used by the servlet (initialized in `init` method, hopefully). The Servlet container is in charge of the lifecycle of the object reference and will call the destroy method before freeing the object reference.

Calling the `destroy` method in the object reference of your servlet won't assure the servlet will be removed from the memory.

The Servlet API doesn't provide a method to unregister servlets. This is the work of the servlet container. The javadoc of [`Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) states it:

> This interface defines methods to initialize a servlet, to service requests, and to remove a servlet from the server. These are known as life-cycle methods and are called in the following sequence:
>
> 1. The servlet is constructed, then initialized with the `init` method.
> 2. Any calls from clients to the `service` method are handled.
> 3. **The servlet is taken out of service, then destroyed with the `destroy` method**, then garbage collected and finalized.

Which means, not even calling the `destroy` method assures the servlet will be *destroyed*.

Comment: @SireeshVattikuti why do you want/need to unload your servlet? Let the servlet container handle it for you.

Comment: I don't want to unload a servlet, i just wanted to know is there is any different ways that a servlet container will unload the servlet?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza good answer. but what is the scenario when destroy method clear all resources used by the servlet, but servlet container will not destroy the servlet

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal E.g. in `init` method you initialize a small cache to avoid going to database which is used on every request (by `doGet` and `doPost` methods), then you invoke `destroy` method and clear the cache, but the servlet is still up and running, so next time it attends a request (via `doXyz` method) it will throw an exception (assuming the code always think the cache is filled up all the time and there's no exception handling around this).

Answer (score 0):

Either by calling destroy method or by shutting down the server.